# How to place blocks of students in certain order?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

How to place blocks of students in 
certain order?

**Instead:**
*if students = 3*

```
Student student student  [css block with student_path]
```

or
 *if students = 5*

```
student student student student
student ["stud_path"] ["stud_path"] [stud_path]
```

**I need:**
*if students = 3*

student student student

or

*if students = 5*

```
student student student student
student
```

**view.rb**

```
<table>
<% if @students %>
    <% @students.in_groups_of(4) do |students| %>
        <tr>
          <% students.each do |student| %>
              <td id="stud"><pre><%= image_tag(student.try(:picture), height:120, width:90 )%> <%= link_to student.try(:display_name), student_path(student.try(:id))%></pre></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<% students.each do |student| %>
  <td id="stud"><pre><%= image_tag(student.try(:picture), height:120, width:90 )%> <%= link_to student.try(:display_name), student_path(student.try(:id))%></pre></td>
<% end %>
```

You need to test whether `student` is nil or not:

```
<% students.each do |student| %>
  <td id="stud">
    <% if student %>
      <pre><%= image_tag(student.picture, height:120, width:90 )%> <%= link_to student.display_name, student_path(student.id)%></pre>
    <% end %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

By doing it inside the `<td></td>` tags you will still preserve the format of the table where the cell is empty.

The test also lets you drop the `try()` method because you know it's not nil.